# Radon-Nikodym property for space of signed measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Given a measurable space, the vector space of signed measures is a Banach space. Does it have the Radon-Nikodym property? What if the space is of a special type, such as a nice topological space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

If there is any related information, such as the Radon-Nikodym property relative to some special measure spaces, I would also be interested.

I assume the answer is well known, but I have not been able to find information in standard sources such as Diestel and Uhl's book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The spaces you are interested in are abstractly AL-spaces and by [Kakutani's representation theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1968915.pdf?casa_token=x9kvIzsjxHUAAAAA:btJzFUxpBLfAZcTE-3USjRKjmUMMNF-uGO24KQdIaD6F0fTqt3pijagbQptR5XaVx3uv1SD2NfUb0WE5GEW5eQHfXawLS61OLV0Nyv2NnW2teq3Plg_P), they can be represented as $L_1(\mu)$ for some measure. In particular, they have the RNP if and only if the measure $\mu$ is purely discrete, in which case $L_1(\mu)$ is isometric to $\ell_1({\rm supp}\, \mu)$.

Thus, for compact spaces $K$, the space of measures $M(K)$ has RNP if and only if $K$ is [scattered](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Scattered_space).

Answer (score 6):

This is more or less the classical example of a space without RNP.  For example,  in the case of the unit interval with the Borel algebra, it is a non separable dual of a separable Banach space and so fails RNP.  More general situations can be dealt with using Stegall’s theorem that the dual of a Banach space $E$ has RNP if and only if every separable subspace thereof has a separable dual, a result which is certainly in Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: I suppose I'm missing some elementary facts. I know that the space of finitely additive signed measures is a dual space. But what is the predual of the space of countably additive signed measures?

Comment: @QuartoBendir: The signed Borel measures on $[0,1]$ are the dual space of $C([0,1])$ (the space of continuous real-valued functions). That's a [classical representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is already answered above. Perhaps it is worth to note the natural "next steps" one would take after this.

If $K$ is a compact topological space and $M(K) = C(K)^{\ast}$, then the following are equivalent.

1. $M(K)$ has RNP.
2. $C(K)$ does not contain a copy of $\ell^1$.
3. $M(K)$ has the Schur property. (weakly convergent sequences are norm convergent)

$(1\Leftrightarrow 2)$ is already answered above.   $(2\Leftrightarrow 3)$ for any Banach space $X$, $X^{\ast}$ has Schur property iff $X$ has Dunford-Pettis property (DPP) and contains no copy of $\ell^1$. $C(K)$ has DPP.

Next step is to generalize this from $C(K)$ to a general $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$.

(a) the following are equivalent for $A$: (see
[Chu](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-24.3.533),
[Huruya](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0375.46051), and
[Jensen](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-11723) for the implication $(4\Rightarrow 1)$)

1. $A^{\ast}$ has RNP.
2. $A$ does not contain a copy of $\ell^1$.
3. $A$ does not contain a copy of $C([0,1])$.
4. If $x\in A$ is self-adjoint, then its spectrum $\sigma(x)$ is countable. (for otherwise $C(\sigma(x))$ and $C([0,1])$ are isomorphic.)

(b) the following are equivalent for $A$ by [Hamana](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-29/issue-1/On-linear-topological-properties-of-some-C-algebras/10.2748/tmj/1178240703.full):

1. $A^{\ast}$ has DPP.
2. $A$ has DPP
3. Every irreducible representation of $A$ is finite dimensional.

(c) Thus by (a)&(b), the following are equivalent for a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$.

1. $A^{\ast}$ has the Schur property.
2. $A^{\ast}$ has DPP and RNP.